# Diamond MultiSite Widget

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using [Diamond MultiSite Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/diamond-multisite-widgets/) in my site. Alongwith post title, url, description, I also want to display the post thumbnail. I have tried many times, contacted the plugin author for help but in vein. Does anyone know how to do it?

Ref: Please check 'Latest Questions' block in [this quotation page](http://smilepls.com/quotes/?p=513).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to get the post id to belong that you get a post thumbnail image of that

Second, you have to display the post-featured Image.

Then this code is not working. please specify your actual requirement.

```
<?php $pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => 1)); ?> 

<?php foreach ($pages as $page): ?>

     <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>
     <h1><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></h1>
     <?php echo $page->post_content; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: 'Post thumbnail' will do. Please specify the widget file/function name that needs to be edited.

Comment: no file or function you have to edited but just use this code to display post thumbnail in any file .